# Understanding the representations of stabilizer groups of points in a stack

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, algebraic-stacks

I'm trying to learn about stacks, but I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something about sheaves on them.

Let $\mathcal X$ be a DM stack over $\mathbb C$, and let $F$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal X}$-modules.

Now let $x\colon \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb C\to \mathcal X$ be a geometric point with nontrivial stabilizer (let's call the stabilizer $G_x$).

How do you understand the action of $G_x$ on the fiber of $F$ over $x$?

I'd be very happy to see a simple example like $\mathcal X=[\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z_3}]$, with $x$ as the unique point with stabilizer $G_x=\mathbb Z_3$. Let's take $F$ to be the sheaf on $\mathcal X$ descending from $\mathcal O_{\mathbb C^2}\otimes V$, with $V$ a nontrivial $\mathbb Z_3$-representation.

It seems to me that the fiber of $F$ over $x$ should just be isomorphic to $V$, but I'm really not sure how to show this properly.